# AngularJS - How to handle promises correctly

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-resource, angularjs-http

I have setup an AngularJS `resource`:

```
app.factory('gridData', function($resource) {
        var csrf = 'asdf';
        return $resource('/my/url/:expID', {expID:'@id'},{
                get: {method:'GET'},
                query: {method:'GET', isArray:true},
                save:{method:'POST', headers: {'X-CSRFToken' : csrf }}
          });
});
```

I'm injecting the `gridData` resource into my controller and using it to fetch data from the server:

```
       gridData.query(function(result) {
            console.log("result is");
            console.log(result);
            $scope.data = result;
        });
```

This approach works fine using AngularJS 1.3. The `console.log(result)` statement prints the actual data received.

Now I tried to downgrade to AngularJS 1.2.11 and I'm having an issue since the `console.log(result)` prints out a promise, as shown in this [picture](http://snag.gy/o9Klt.jpg). Consequently `$scope.data` is set to the promise, but I actually need $scope.data set only when the actual data is available.

This is because in some version between 1.3 and 1.2 promises have been introduced into Angular. Any idea how to handle this situation / correctly deal with promises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the section titled "The Promise API" in [the docs on the $q service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q). You can also checkout [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-promises) on Angular promises.

The main method you need to know about is `.then`. Here's how you could refactor your code with this method:

```
gridData.query(function(promise) {
            promise.then(function (result) {
              console.log("result is");
              console.log(result);
              $scope.data = result;
            });
        });
```

This example could be cleaner, but it works for illustrative purposes. Hope that helps.

Comment: I faced the same problem after migration 1.2 -> 1.3. My method looks like exactly as yours. I couldn't understand why it works in this way and forced to use the workaround like this: delete $scope.myObj.$resolved; delete $scope.myObj.$promise;